# How to auto-update javascript in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which have a server-side javascript and I need this js to be reloaded every [1] hour on the client side. What´s the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**
Bump your extension version every couple of hours. Chrome will automatically update the extension: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html.

**Method 2**, distinguishing cases:

- JSON: When the "server-side JS" only contains data, this is the best solution. Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) in the [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) to regularly update the variables. Do **not** forget to set the [permissions in `manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions), to enable cross-origin XHR.
  The response can be parsed with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
- Script: Another option is to dynamically inject `<script>` tags in the background page.

> ### Warning: Loading and executing external scripts in the background page poses a potential security hole in the extension.
>
> When the network connection or your server is compromised, an evil third party can execute arbitrary code with your extension's privileges!

Comment: Thanks Rob again. You helped are helping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your question in more clear way. As far as i understand you want to update the js-code on client-side every hour. If so, you can't do this in chrome extensions.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry. So it can´t be done that way. What if I want my extension to be reloaded every [1] hour?

Comment: It depends on what you want your extension to do. If you just want your js-file to be reloaded, you can simply set a timeout-function which will call window.location.reload() every hour.